# I'm trying to run a Python SDK and am getting errors from runpy.py. How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, sdk

```
(base) kiin@kiin ~ % python3 -m anki_vector.configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kiin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
File "/Users/kiin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
__import__(pkg_name)
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anki_vector/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from . import messaging
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anki_vector/messaging/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
from . import client
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anki_vector/messaging/client.py", line 23, in <module>
from .alexa_pb2_grpc import *
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anki_vector/messaging/alexa_pb2_grpc.py", line 2, in <module>
import grpc
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from grpc import _compression
File "/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kiin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (_CFRelease)
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK, as well as downgrade to Python 3.8. Same errors for both.

Comment: You should make it more clear in your post what SDK you are referring to and what steps you've completed. I assume you've read these pages: https://developer.anki.com/vector/docs/initial.html, https://developer.anki.com/vector/docs/troubleshooting.html (this one has a section on failure to run anki_vector.configure). There is a link to their discussion forum too.